# UI-Bootstrap datepicker with input mask

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, masking

Currently trying to use a standard datepicker but combine it with an input mask to make it easier to enter the date by hand if the user needs to.

[See Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/6tGAnLDphUgBEQUXdjN4?p=preview)

The problem at the moment is that when I add the mask one of two things happens, either hand typing the date into the field doesn't work (meaning as soon as I finish it deletes the value from the field) *OR* it succeeds in updating the model value but when I open the `datepicker` it is set to the year `1500`.

The plunk has both a masked and unmasked version of the input.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="'2010-01-02'" max-date="dt" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" show-weeks="false" show-button-bar="false" ui-mask="99/99/9999" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
```

JS

```
.controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.dt = new Date();

  $scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = true;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

datetimepicker master is the solution

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker_mask').datetimepicker({
 timepicker:false,
 mask:true, // '9999/19/39 29:59' - digit is the maximum possible for a cell
});
```

http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need mask as the api will do it for you

```
<input class='form-control' data-provide='datepicker' data-date-format='yyyy-mm-dd'>
```

Comment: Sometimes, a user want to type in the textbox instead of using mouse on the date picker.

Comment: This is not working. maybe it needs additional library.